# Upgrade to JBoss 7 Datasource is Not Working

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to upgrade to JBoss 7; however, my datasource is not creating a connection. I did not deploy any WAR files. I am testing the connection by using the admin console. In standalone.xml, I configured the datasource as follows:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/projectDS" pool-name="projectDS" enabled="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcc-67-150.usae.ABC.com:1521:test</connection-url>
            <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
            <driver>ojdbc6</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>XXX</user-name>
                <password>XXX</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="ojdbc6" module="com.oracle" />
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

The ojdbc6.jar driver is in the following folder %JBOSS_HOME%\modules\com\oracle\main. The entry in my module.xml reads as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
         <module name="javax.api"/>
         <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

The error that I receive in my server log when I test the connection from the admin console is:

```
07:47:11,863 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool]
(HttpManagementService-threads - 4) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get
a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create conne
ction
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLo
calManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1
.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should also note that this connection works inside the firewall. However, when I work from home, the firewall blocks the connection. I am still able to connect with JBoss 5 while working from home. Is there something to look for in my JBoss 5 configuration that I can add to the JBoss 7 configuration?

Answer (score 0):

1. Deploy the oracle driver jar to jboss from the console. Its something like localhost:9990/console with credential test/test123
2. From the datasource option, check whether you can see your datasource **java:jboss/hqiis** over there or not. If not, try to create the datasource from the console instead of configuring through xml.
3. Also check the data source status from the jboss-cli:

   a. From command prompt, enter into JBOSS_HOME\bin

   b. Type connect YOUR_IP:YOUR_PORT (example 192.169.1.10:9999)

   c. Type this to see whether your datasource is available or not:

   /subsystem=datasources/data-source=hqiis:test-connection-in-pool

   You should see a msg like below if you are having a configured datasource named **hqiis**

   connection-in-pool
   {
       "outcome" => "success",
       "result" => [true]
   }

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, even when I start from the beginning by creating a datascource using the console, I get the same error when I try the 'Test Connection' button in the console. The jboss-cli client cannot connect to the address provided. Finally;, the last command that you mentioned failed because of no connection being establish. :(

Comment: @user3071829: did you find a solution to this problem?